Images of structure preserving maps are structures?
Context: I have been working with (mostly concrete) categories like Sets, Groups, Rings, Vect$_k$, Ab, $R$-Mod, Top, Diff and so on. As I understand it, images of group maps are subgroups of their co-domain groups. Hence images of group maps are groups. Same for other “algebraic categories” in my list.
However, this seems to break down for Top and Diff (the category of smooth manifolds and smooth maps between them). In Top I need to specify a topology on the image of the continuous map and it somehow “does not come automatically with a topology” unlike group images which come with a group structure ie the the group structure inherited from the co-domain group. In fact one can show that if the underlying set of the image of a group map has a group structure, then it is indeed this subgroup structure inherited from the co-domain group.
Moreover, in Top it may seem somewhat canonical to equip the image with the subspace topology of the co-domain space. At least, it is the coarsest topology that makes the inclusion of the image of a continuous map into its image continuous. However, unlike in Groups, this is not the only structure on the image that makes the inclusion continuous.
I feel like, things get even worse in Diff, where it seems to be the case that except when the smooth maps are also smooth embeddings or injective smooth immersions, there is no canonical choice of topology and smooth structure for the image of a smooth map. For instance the figure “8” curve is not even a manifold wrt subspace topology even though it is the image of a smooth map (its not smoothly embedded but it is smoothly immersed in the plane.
Question: Why is this happening? More precisely, why is it that in categories of groups and rings, images of structure preserving maps are sets with those structures, but NOT in Top or Diff? Is there a category theory explanation for this?
One possible argument I could expect is that smooth structure and indeed topology are structures that we need add on to sets. But I would really like to see some elaboration on this, if possible.

As Grothendieck once said, Diff is a category with nice objects and terrible morphisms.

One possible answer is that not everything in math should be viewed through the prism of the Category Theory. Just try to explain to somebody in PDEs relevance of the Category Theory: They have neither objects, nor morphisms. And yet, this is a very important part of math.

Great question! To my mind the most profitable way to understand it is to turn it around and ask:

Can we define the image of a morphism in a purely categorical way? If so, when this definition is applied to concrete categories, when do we recover the set-theoretic image in the usual sense, and when do we recover something else?

The answer is not at all obvious: in a category which has finite limits and colimits (which includes all of your examples except $\text{Diff}$), there are (at least) two different notions of image, namely the regular image and regular coimage $\text{im}(f), \text{coim}(f)$, which are categorically dual. They naturally fit into a refined "coimage-image" factorization
$$X \to \text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f) \to Y$$
which dualizes to the coimage-image factorization in the opposite category. The actual definitions are a little unfamiliar but they are both just built out of simple limits and colimits. $\text{coim}(f)$ is the coequalizer of what is called the kernel pair of $f$, which is the pullback of $f$ along itself, while $\text{im}(f)$ is the categorical dual, the equalizer of the cokernel pair, which is the pushout of $f$ along itself. For a brief discussion you can see here and for a longer discussion of the kernel and cokernel pair you can see here.
So, here's what happens when you try to apply this definition to the categories you've listed.

In every category of models of an algebraic theory, the kernel pair $\ker(f)$ is just $\{ (x_1, x_2) \in X^2 : f(x_1) = f(x_2) \}$, and $\text{coim}(f)$ is the set-theoretic image with the usual operations. This includes $\text{Set}, \text{Grp}, \text{Ab}, \text{Mod}(R), \text{Ring}$, and $\text{CRing}$. However, $\text{im}(f)$ is potentially different, because the cokernel pair can behave funnily.

In $\text{Set}$, $\text{Grp}$, $\text{Ab}$, and $\text{Mod}(R)$, the map $\text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f)$ is always an isomorphism; this is a kind of "generalized isomorphism theorem," and is the reason you've never heard of the coimage before. This condition is so nice it is part of the definition of an abelian category; the coimage turns out to generalize $\text{coker}(\ker(f))$ while the image generalizes $\ker(\text{coker}(f))$. Interestingly another example where this condition holds is $\text{Comp}$, the category of compact Hausdorff spaces.

In $\text{Ring}$ and $\text{CRing}$ the coimage is just the usual set-theoretic image as above, but I don't actually know what the image looks like in general. However, as a suggestive special case, if $f : R \to S^{-1} R$ is a localization in $\text{CRing}$, then its coimage is $R$ but its image is $S^{-1} R$.

In $\text{Top}$, if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map then $\text{coim}(f)$ is the set-theoretic image but given the quotient topology from $X$, while $\text{im}(f)$ is the set-theoretic image but given the subspace topology from $Y$. These are respectively the finest and the coarsest topologies making both the quotient from $X$ and the inclusion into $Y$ continuous. So you're correct that there isn't a unique such topology, but there is both an initial and a terminal such topology, and that's the best we can say in general.

$\text{Diff}$ does not have finite limits or colimits in general, so in general neither the coimage nor the image is even defined. Concretely this is reflected in things like the intersection of submanifolds failing to be a manifold, and quotients of manifolds failing to be manifolds. This is why it's the least well-behaved of your examples; it's just a very poorly-behaved category. This can be fixed by passing to a larger category like the category of smooth sets, which is much better-behaved: it is a topos.


It's probably also worth saying something more concrete about this:

why is it that in categories of groups and rings, images of structure preserving maps are sets with those structures

You can just work through the general argument, which is valid in any category of models of an algebraic theory: on the image of a homomorphism $f : A \to B$ of algebraic structures, if we want to define some operation in our signature, there are two ways to do it:

We choose a lift of all our elements to $A$ and perform the operation there, then pass back down to the image via $f$. Then, using the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism, we show that this does not depend on the choice of lifts.
We use the operation in $B$. Using the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism, we show that the image is closed under the operation.

These always agree (again, using the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism), and this is the unique way to define operations on the set-theoretic image making both the quotient from $A$ and the inclusion into $B$ homomorphisms.
$\text{Top}$ and $\text{Diff}$ are simply not defined in this way in terms of algebraic operations, so this argument doesn't apply to them. Interestingly, $\text{Comp}$ can be defined in this way, using infinitary operations coming from ultrafilters, and the above argument correctly applies to this case. The closest $\text{Top}$ gets to being defined this way is in terms of the Kuratowski closure axioms, and if you use those axioms to work out what topology you get on the set-theoretic image of a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ I think (but have not checked carefully) that in the first approach you get the quotient topology, whereas in the second approach you get the subspace topology.
But $\text{Diff}$ is not just a category of objects equipped with a certain kind of structure, it is really a category of objects satisfying a niceness condition, namely being locally Euclidean (among other things). Niceness conditions generally just are not preserved by categorical operations like taking quotients, which is why e.g. we don't consider the category of fields by itself but we embed it into the much better-behaved category of commutative rings. $\text{Diff}$ can be embedded into several different better-behaved larger categories depending on what you want to do, like the category of smooth sets mentioned above, or the truly enormous category of locally ringed spaces.

Thanks Qiaochu :)) I am a bit busy with coursework right now, will read your wonderful answer thoroughly and get back in a short while.

Is there a source where I can learn more about niceness conditions? I have seen the isomorphism theorem for abelian categories, and know kernel of cokernel and cokernel of kernel from there. But how useful are the notions of regular (co)-image? Btw really appreciate the answer, gives me a better picture of things :))

@frelg: well, this is an informal term I just coined, I don't know if there's a technical term and it's also a very general and kind of vague term. I would say that I have never needed the regular image for anything but the regular coimage actually seems to do the sensible thing in practice. You need the regular coimage (or really you need the kernel pair) to state a version of the isomorphism theorem for monoids, for example.

@frelg: here is a different example of "niceness conditions." If you start studying commutative algebra to apply it to algebraic geometry you might want for various reasons to restrict your attention only to, say, reduced rings (rings with no nilpotents), since those seem like the most geometric examples. However natural constructions on reduced rings can produce unreduced rings; for example the tensor product of reduced rings need not be reduced. Nilpotents turn out to encode meaningful geometric information, although it took time and experience to understand this.

Thank you very much, very useful information :))
